# Why does the ntimes doesn't add one in child process?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork

Here is the code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ntimes = 0;

int main()
{
  int pid,ppid;
  int p_action(),c_action();

  /* set parent process SIGUSR1 */
  signal(SIGUSR1,p_action);

  switch(pid=fork()){
  case -1: /* fork failed */
    perror("synchro");
    exit(1);
  case 0:  /* child process mode */
    /* set child process SIGUSR1 */
    signal(SIGUSR1,c_action);

    /* get parent process */
    ppid = getppid();

    for(;;){
      sleep(1);
      kill(ppid,SIGUSR1);
      pause();
    }

    /* dead loop */
    break;

  default: /* parent process mode */
    for(;;){
      pause();
      sleep(1);
      kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
    }
    /* dead loop*/
  }

  return 0;
}

p_action()
{
  printf("Parent caught signal #%d\n",++ntimes);
}

c_action()
{
  printf("Child caught signal #%d\n",++ntimes);
}
```

And the output is:

Parent caught signal #1
Child caught signal #1
Parent caught signal #2
Child caught signal #2
Parent caught signal #3
Child caught signal #3
.
.
.

Why the ntimes for child is the same to the parent but not ++1, like parent-1, child-2, parent-3, child-4, ...

Thank you!

Comment: BTW, the code as shown does not use any loop, so the output you give had been created by some other source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent and child(dren) do *not* share the same set of variables.

The parent's variables are "copied" to child on its creation, from than on the child uses its own variables independently, the same the parent does with its variables.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense to me